# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'state.children[state.index].sceneKey

Tags: firebase

While working with react-native as a frontend and firebase as a backend I have created an manger application in which the manager can add, delete or edit employees and their details.

The employee details are edited only once i.e while login into the application after that if I try to edit the employee details it gives the error.

[image: undefined is not an object]

Comment: can you please share the code!

Comment: thankyou for your response...which part of the code you need

Comment: what you are doing on edit employee

Comment: i am sharing my github link...please check it out.... https://github.com/kalyanipullela/employee

Answer (score 0):

In first render state.children is empty!

In render change code and checking exist object before write 
Etc :

```
enter code here
If(this.state.children.length>0){
    This.state.children.map({});
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your reponse...but i didn't understand....can you please explain in detail?